# PagerAdapter is abstract; cannot be instantiated error. How can i fix it?

Tags: java, android, adapter

My MainActivity.Java folder like that. I did all import but It gives error "PagerAdapter is abstract; cannot be instantiated"

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

BottomBar bottomBar; //Bottomnavigationbar

//ViewPager için oluşturulan ListAdapterde ki fragmentList
List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //viewpager tanımlanması (ana ekrandan kaydırıp kamera ve mesajlaşma kısımlarının oluşturulması için)
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    //fragmentlist'e gerekli fragmentlerin eklenmesi
    fragmentList.add(new ViewPager_Camera());
    fragmentList.add(new ViewPager_Home());
    fragmentList.add(new ViewPager_Message());

   PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),fragmentList);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Bottombar tanımlanması ve selectlistener özelliği aktif edilmesi
    bottomBar = (BottomBar) findViewById(R.id.bottom_bar);
```

My PagerAdapter is like that

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

//fragmentList tanımlanması
List<Fragment>  fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();


public PagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior,List<Fragment>fragList) {
    super(fm, behavior);
    this.fragmentList = fragList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    //hangi fragment açıksa listeden de o fragment isteniyor
    return fragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    //fragmetlist boyutu kadar fragment oldugunu gösteriyor
    return fragmentList.size();
}
```

}

How can I fix this error? I tryed to change adapter name but still had error. May the problem be in the methos using?

Comment: What error did you get when you changed the name?

Comment: Still same error "PagerAdapter is abstract; cannot be instantiated"

Comment: If you changed the name, why are you still trying to instantiate `PagerAdapter`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the class you're extending, FragmentPagerAdapter, is an abstract class with abstract methods which you are not overriding.  Since your class still has at least one abstract method, it is an abstract class and therefore cannot be instantiated.

Look in the base class for other abstract methods, and override those, too.

Answer (score 0):

PagerAdapter is also a framework class (androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter) which is abstract. Your MainActivity is probably using the wrong class.

Rename your PagerAdapter class to something else and see (MyPagerAdapter?).